# Excel: Fleshing out column data by another column ID

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with multiple rows that have the same "Subject ID" with a column (Value A) that will always have the same value by subject ID (or be empty).  Example:

```
╔══════════════════════════╗
║ | subject id | value A | ║
╠══════════════════════════╣
║ |:----------:|---------| ║
║ |      1     |    A    | ║
║ |      1     |    A    | ║
║ |      1     |         | ║
║ |      1     |         | ║
║ |      2     |         | ║
║ |      2     |         | ║
║ |      2     |    B    | ║
╚══════════════════════════╝
```

How can I in Excel create a formula that I can drag down the Value A column such that it gives all of the rows with the same subject ID the same value for Value A?  There is no situation in my data in which there would be different values in the Value A column for a particular subject ID: it will either have a value or not.

For example, with this I want to make it so that all of the subjects with an ID of one get a Value A of "A", and for every record with a subject id of 2, I want it to receive a value of "B". Example:

```
╔══════════════════════════╗
║ | subject id | value A | ║
╠══════════════════════════╣
║ |:----------:|---------| ║
║ |      1     |    A    | ║
║ |      1     |    A    | ║
║ |      1     |    A    | ║
║ |      1     |    A    | ║
║ |      2     |    B    | ║
║ |      2     |    B    | ║
║ |      2     |    B    | ║
╚══════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Are these your actual subject ids?  I would assume that this is a simplification of your data.  If it is then the answers below will work and you should give feedback and mark one of them correct by clicking the check mark by the answer that you used, if not you will not be able to do this in place with formula and would need a third column in which the Value A is put or vba to do it in place.

Comment: The IDs and the contents of the Value A column are simplifications: there is no inherent relationship between the ID and the value in the other field (which is numeric in my real data set). I apologize for the confusion, but none of the answers provided thus far actually answer my question since they assume an inherent relationship that doesn't exist.

Comment: Then, are you looking for in place with vba, or using a third column with formulas?

Comment: I'd be fine either.

Comment: For formula; do some research into INDEX/MATCH array formulas.  For VBA use loops.

Answer (score 0):

Use Char to convert the number to a char using the ASCII code.

Note, this will only work up to a value of 26, after that you run out of letters and will start getting brackets and other chars

```
=CHAR(A2+64)
```

Comment: The "Value A" column can contain most anything (and is numeric in my data set). There is no inherent relationship between the ID and the value in that field, so your formula isn't much assistance

Answer (score 0):

Extending on Dan's solution, this solution should work on more than 26 different IDs

```
=IF(A1>26,CHAR(QUOTIENT(A1-1,26)+64),"") & CHAR(1+MOD(A1-1,26)+64)
```

Where A1 has the ID. this formulae gives in the below results

```
1   A
2   B
.
.
.
26  Z
27  AA
28  AB
29  AC
.
.
.
44  AR
45  AS
.
.
.
53  BA
54  BB
55  BC
```

Comment: The "Value A" column can contain most anything (and is numeric in my data set). There is no inherent relationship between the ID and the value in that field, so your formula isn't much assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my results:

```
+------------+---------+----------------+
| subject id | value A | Formula result |
+------------+---------+----------------+
|          1 |         | Hello          |
|          1 |         | Hello          |
|          1 | Hello   | Hello          |
|          1 |         | Hello          |
|          1 |         | Hello          |
|          1 |         | Hello          |
|          2 |         | B              |
|          2 | B       | B              |
|          2 | B       | B              |
|          2 |         | B              |
|          2 |         | B              |
|          2 | B       | B              |
|          3 |         | World          |
|          3 |         | World          |
|          3 | World   | World          |
|          3 |         | World          |
|          3 |         | World          |
|          4 |         | D              |
|          4 | D       | D              |
|          4 |         | D              |
|          4 |         | D              |
+------------+---------+----------------+
```

I built a UDF for it the formula in C2 is =GetCode(A2,$A$2:$A$22,1) where the first parameter is the value to search for, the second is the range to search in and the last is the columns to offset to look for a result.

Code below:

```
Function GetCode(InputValue As String, SearchRange As Range, ColOffset As Long)
Dim TempVal As String, FirstFoundRow As Long, LastFoundRow As Long, X As Long
On Error Resume Next 'If not found the result will be null
TempVal = Null
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SearchRange, InputValue) > 0 Then
    FirstFoundRow = SearchRange.Find(InputValue).Row 'Determine the rows to check
    LastFoundRow = SearchRange.Find(InputValue, , , , , xlPrevious).Row 'Find the last row, no need to test after that
    For X = FirstFoundRow To LastFoundRow 'Loop the checking rows
        TempVal = SearchRange.Cells(X, ColOffset + 1).Text 'Assign the value of the offset column for the tested row
        If TempVal <> "" Then Exit For 'Quit the loop if it has found the answer
    Next
End If
GetCode = TempVal
End Function
```

Assumption:
subject ID is sorted. If it is not it will give the WRONG results, it would be simple enough for you to modify the code to search through instances in none contiguous data.

note: Please try to format your question with a little more **key** detail, all the previous answers made the same assumption I did (When you have 1 - A, 2 - B as your sample data it's an easy thing to assume) and also with reference to my above assumption, I had to make the assumption of sorted data as you didn't tell us.

A none code option would have been to take a copy, remove dupes, sort on col B to remove the blanks then use a VLOOKUP formula against the freshly created matrix.